# Random filter a python list of dictionary to get a new list of dictionary based on same key name

Tags: python, list

I want to form a new list of dictionaries by random choosing dictionary from existing list of dictionary based on same key name.

```
existing_list = [{'topic1': 'question1'}, {'topic2': 'question2'}, {'topic3': 'question3'}, {'topic2': 'question4'}, {'topic2': 'question5'}, {'topic1': 'question2'}, {'topic1': 'question3'}, {'topic3': 'question5'}, {'topic3': 'question6'}]
```

The new list should choose two random dictionary having same key name:

```
 new_list = [{'topic1': 'question1'}, {'topic1': 'question3'}, {'topic2': 'question2'}, {'topic2': 'question5'}, {'topic3': 'question5'}, {'topic3': 'question3'}]
```

Taking suggestions below i change the data structures:

```
arrange = {}
for item in questions:
    arrange.setdefault(item['parent'], []).append(item['question_link'])

    question_lists_of_lists = [random.sample(arrange[topic], 2) for topic in arrange]
    question_lists= sum(question_lists_of_lists,[])
```

Now i am looking for better alternative to achieve the new list using:

```
new_list = []
for k, v in arrange.items():
    for i in range(2):
        random_value = random.choice(v)
        new_list.append({k: random_value})
        arrange[k].remove(random_value)
```

Comment: What if there is a dictionary that has no duplicated keys?

Comment: Did my code answer your question?

Comment: @BokiX the first part of better data structure i am using setdefault to achieve. That is no problem. Later part of random choice is there any way to do this using list comprehension instead of for loop

Comment: What do you want to use if not a for loop? Why do you even want an alternative?

Comment: Why do you have `for i in range(1)` if you need 2 elements with the same key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is the code that you are looking for:

```
import random
existing_list = [{'topic1': 'question1'}, {'topic2': 'question2'}, {'topic3': 'question3'}, {'topic2': 'question4'}, {'topic2': 'question5'}, {'topic1': 'question2'}, {'topic1': 'question3'}, {'topic3': 'question5'}, {'topic3': 'question6'}]
new_list = []
d = {}  # creating a new dictionary for better storage overview

# adding key-value pairs into the dictionary
for element in existing_list:
    for k, v in element.items():
        if k in d.keys():
            d[k].append(v)
        else:
            d[k] = [v,]

# randomly choosing values from the dictionary
for k, v in d.items():
    for i in range(2):
        random_value = random.choice(v)
        new_list.append({k: random_value})
        d[k].remove(random_value)

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your main problem is how you store your data. having a list of dictionaries with a single key-value pair is not that easy to work with.

a better approach might be to store the different questions in a list for each topic so kind of like this:

```
d = {'topic1': [question1, question2, question3], 'topic2': [question1, question2, question3]}
```

then you can iterate through the dictionary like so:

```
for topic, questions in d.items():
    q1 = d[topic][random(0, len(questions)].pop()
    q2 = d[topic][random(0, len(questions)].pop()
```

then you can store those questions in some list or use them however you want.

(btw the list.pop() method actually removes the element from list but since 'questions' is a local variable in the loop it should be fine i think)